Python signal handler doesn't terminate process before program exits
I'm want to terminate my python script smoothly by using a signal handler. But with a keyboard interruption the handler doesn't finish before the program exits.
Any hints on how to get the handler to do the termination?
import sys,subprocess,signal

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    zipProc.terminate()
    zipProc.wait()
    sys.exit('Stopped')

test_dir = '/mnt/Z/testdir'
out_file = '/mnt/Z/testdir.7z'
cmd = ['7z', 'a', '-t7z', out_file, test_dir]
zipProc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
zipProc.communicate()
for sig in [signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGQUIT, signal.SIGHUP]:
    signal.signal(sig, signal_handler)


Set the handler before running the process-

signal handlers are not inherited by subprocesses. So the subprocess runs with default signal disposition.

Those signals are being delivered to a process group.
So both parent and child get them.
We have an opportunity to make parent obey them and child ignore them.
Rather than directly forking off 7z, fork off this 7z.sh script:
#! /usr/bin/env bash

trap '' SIGTERM SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGHUP  # ignore signals
echo "$@"
exec "$@"

Remove the echo debug once you have seen that it's working.
The script will run whatever arguments you give it,
with those signals disabled.
The parent should install handlers prior to forking a worker:
for sig in [signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGQUIT, signal.SIGHUP]:
    signal.signal(sig, signal_handler)
cmd = ['./7z.sh', '7z', 'a', '-t7z', out_file, test_dir]
zipProc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
zipProc.communicate()

And it wouldn't hurt to make the handler a bit more chatty during debugging.
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print(f'Handling {sig}...')
    zipProc.terminate()
    print('Waiting...')
    zipProc.wait()
    print('Done.')
    sys.exit('Stopped')

man pages
Here are some relevant excerpts.
https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve

All process attributes are preserved during an execve(), except the following:
The dispositions of any signals that are being caught are reset to the default (signal(7)). ...

https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIG_IGN

... standard signal handler, which will simply ignore the given signal.

https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal
A child created via fork(2) inherits a copy of its parent's signal dispositions. During an execve(2), the dispositions of handled signals are reset to the default; the dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl

These functions all execute a new program, replacing the current process ...

I proposed

parent: python
child: bash, then 7z

just because it's trivial to code up.
But one could also get this to work.

parent: python
child: python, then 7z

The detail is: the child python would have to ignore four signals
prior to exec'ing 7z.
I don't mean "write a tiny handler which simply does pass".
The child python would need to use signal.SIG_IGN.

Thanks @J_H, it works great!  The wait() wasn't needed and I added SIGTSTP to the list of my signals in python to handle Ctrl-z.  But it turns out that SIGTSTP didn't need to be added to the trap in 7z.sh...any ideas why?

When I put this structure in my bigger python code, I had to add sleep(0.1) before and after the terminate() to get it to work consistently.
